# Contour correction based on points

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y28r0.png)
[Corrected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er2DB.png)

The first picture contains a contour that I have. The contour is made up of a set of points. I would like to ask if you know an algoritm that would allow me to correct the contour by moving my cursor from point A to point B (it's marked on the second picture). The main task is to correct the contour with my cursor withoy making sharp edges, these edges need to be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the same movement vector multiplied by a factor thats gets smaller for higher distance to original point